# The method implicitlyWait(long, TimeUnit) from the type WebDriver.Timeouts is deprecated what is that Mean really?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, wait, webdriverwait, implicit

```
please resolve issue , please update the same
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(());
        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

The method implicitlyWait(long, TimeUnit) from the type WebDriver.Timeouts is deprecated, what is that Mean really?

Comment: what is the issue, which version of selnium you are using

Answer (score 4):

`Deprecated`

It means the method `implicitlyWait(long, TimeUnit)` is no more supported and you should use an updated method to serve the same purpose.

You can change your code to

```
long time = 2000;
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(time));
```

Instead of arguments `(long, TimeUnit)`, this method now takes arguments as `Duration.ofSeconds(time)`

Comment: If you got `error: cannot find symbol Duration`, import it from `java.time.Duration`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this :

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

If you are using selenium 4 try this:

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    driver.manage().timeouts().scriptTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60));
```